# Can the physical MAC address be changed in/or by VMware?

Tags: vmware

The physical network address of my NIC (Killer E2400) changed after having tested some distributions of Linux under VMware.

Before it was a Micro-Star address (4C:CC:6A...) now it's a VMware address (00-0C-29 ...).

Booting another OS changed nothing, so I think that it is the real address which changed.

How is that possible? I thought that it was written in the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you posted to StackExchange Writing site? But saw your question there.

The MAC address is written in the hardware but it's easily changed by an ifconfig command. This isn't permanent but can be made so by an entry in one of the system config files.

This should help you:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address/Linux

But, in case the link breaks, to change temporarily:

> Under GNU/Linux, the MAC address of a network interface card (NIC) can be changed by following the procedures below.
>
> NOTE: MAC addresses used within this article are provided for example
>   only. Substitute according to your requirements. NOTE: Commands below
>   MUST be executed with root privileges (e.g. prepended with "sudo "),
>   in order for things to work!
>
> /etc/init.d/networking stop ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:01:02:03:04:08
>   /etc/init.d/networking start Execute "ifconfig eth0" to confirm.

And to change permanently (since your question suggests that you didn't make this change, you may want to check the config file mentioned for alterations):

> In openSUSE and other SUSE-based systems (SUSE enterprise
>   desktop\server, etc.) you can make changes "permanent" across reboots
>   by adding an appropriate entry to the
>   /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-ethN file (ifcfg-eth0 for the first
>   Ethernet interface config file, ifcfg-eth1 - for the second, etc.):
>
> LLADDR=12:34:56:78:90:ab In Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) and other
>   similar systems (Fedora, CentOS, etc.) an easy way to make changes
>   "permanent" across reboots is to add an appropriate entry to the
>   /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethN file (ifcfg-eth0 for the
>   first Ethernet interface config file, ifcfg-eth1 - for the second,
>   etc.):
>
> MACADDR=12:34:56:78:90:ab

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will interfere with your ability to edit your questions/answers. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: What is the downvote for?

Comment: @LateralTerminal - The original revision appeared to be [spam](https://superuser.com/revisions/1296966/1) and I flagged it as such.

Comment: @DavidPostill Certainly not intentionally, I was logged in as me when I posted but it wouldn't post my answer without verifying me on this stack. Followed link and here we are. Will merge.

Comment: @Ramhound What, because I pasted a link to an answer for the OP? I pasted the relevant sections almost immediately, but this stack has a mediator for edits, which slowed it down. But, cheers for the downvotes! This OP posted on the StackExchange Writers site, it was a simple answer, so I thought I'd help out. But wow. To quote, *You've Got Mail*: "This place is a tomb. I'm going [back] to the nut shop where it's fun."

Comment: @GGx - Edits to your own answer don't require approval. The fact you used the second account isn't the fault of anyone here.  We are spammed daily by users, who submit very similar answers, which just contain minor relevant information and links to websites.  I personally never heard of the website you linked to but recognized the URL pattern, of websites, are contained in actual spam contributions.

Comment: (continued)....I obviously do not click on those spam links, but information click-bait websites, are easy to identify by the URL.  Typically the URL contains the exact keywords, and the page, ends up being created the same day.  Worth pointing out the spam flag was declined, the reputation returned, so the other two votes were actual users who found this answer to be less than helpful in its previous revision.  I see now the website is owned Wikipedia.....I also might not have actually flagged it nor did I vote on it....so disregard my previous comment about the spam flag.

Comment: @Ramhound You're missing my point, which wasn't aimed directly at you, or DavidPostill who put a comment re: the two accounts and asked me to copy & paste rather than link. Which is fair enough (dual accts cause edit mediation BTW). My sass is because it's a very different experience on the Writing stack. This OP's question was downvoted 3 time without a single comment to help him with why or suggestions to reword. The answer fine, downvote it, but at least put a better answer to help out the OP that other people can upvote. That's the whole point of these stacks. Back to the nut shop for me!

Answer (score -1):

I restored my original MAC address by clearing the CMOS.

I will probably never know why or how VMware has changed it.